# Automatic timers for 4-way switch, or how to automatically turn off lights in a stairwell

Tags: electrical, lighting

We have a stairwell which goes from the first to third floor of the house, with a landing on the second floor. It's a straight shot all the way up, with the landing in the middle. There are switches at the top, bottom and on the landing, (there is a door to the second floor on the landing).

It's currently set up with two 3-way and a 4-way switch so you can turn the lights on and off from any of the switches. The problem is that these lights end up always being left on.

Any ideas on how to either replace one or all of the switches such that if the light is on for more than 10 minutes, it turns off?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring in the switch boxes?

Comment: You're up against building codes which *absolutely require* a way to turn the light on from each stairway entry.  if the timer decides the light must be off, and the human decides the light must be on, the human must win.  Also it's a codevio and liabilility for you if the light turns off *while* someone is traversing the stairs,  That can't happen.

Comment: @Harper occupancy sensors at each level wired so that "any" can close the circuit with a 5 minute timeout should meet could, they also meet the manual on requiremment.

Comment: @tyson the problem with any timeout is that a second person comes along, finds the light already on, and proceeds without further thought.  Unbeknownst to them, the timer is about to run out, and does so while they are mid flight.   The motion sensor tries to mitigate this risk, but that's only as good as the motion sensor -which in my experience in corridors (especially stairways!!) is terrible.

Comment: @Harper if each level has a timer that restarts the countdown on any motion, and any activated level can close the circuit then say someone goes up from 1 to 3, that turns the light on when level 1 detects motion, and it's not turned off til 5 minutes after the timeout on level 3.  If person B comes along at any level, they re-trip whatever level or level... Extending on time.  It's common to use multiple occupancy sensors wired as "any", the light comes on at "first sensor motion" and goes off at "last sensor timeout".

Comment: @Harper here is a [wiring diagram and discussion](http://www.renovation-headquarters.com/wiring-multiple-motion-sensors.html) for using multiple motion and occupancy sensors.   It works because when "any" sensor sees motion it holds the light on, when the LAST sensors time delay expires then the light turns off.  Any other people causing motion at any sensor just keep the light on longer.

Comment: @Tyson, the issue with that diagram, is that it is for a single switch. As mentioned above, I need to have switches on each landing, So right now I have 2 - three way, and a 4 way switch to control the lights.

I was hoping they made 3 and four way switches, with occupancy sensors, that would work together. i.e. Turn the lights off if there are no people.

Comment: @bpeikes generally 3/4-way wiring can be converted to work with multiple occupancy sensors.  (My example was conceptual for Harper) in your case tho, more info is needed.  Specifically whether or not you have a neutral in all 3 switch boxes.  If you do, then one traveller will be repurposed as hot, the other traveller will be repurposed for load.  If you don't have neutral in all 3 locations then you need to specifically tell us more about circuit and include photos with showing the insides of all the boxes.

Comment: I have installed 3way electronic motion switches I believe they can have more as they are digitally controlled but you will need a neutral in each of the 3 locations will try to find them when I have some time they were made by leviton and had a off delay. + tyson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A leviton ods10 ID will do the trick or 3 of them. The ones I used years ago needed a neutral but a quick read on these stated they don't need a neutral and will work as 3 way and 4 way looks to be about 35$ I put these in 1 area that had 3 entries back in 2000 or 2001 still working today.

Answer (score 0):

Without any actual wiring diagrams or a picture of the wiring itself I would suggest a light with a presence sensor that has a timer inside. 
Almost all lamps of this type turn on when power is applied to them, even though they don't sense anyone.
Set the timer inside them to 10 minutes and when you switch the light on it will open. After 10 minutes of inactivity it will shutdown. If the lights are switched off and and the sensor does not 'see' you, simply switch the light twice. Once for power off then for power on.

If you post a picture with the wiring, we might come with a better solution.

Comment: I need the ability to have people turn the lights in the stairwell on manually from all three landings.